# Get data from array of object using a another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two separated arrays like this

```
 ages = [20,40,60];

 doctors = [{
  "name": "Moruu",
  "age": 18,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Africa"
},
{
  "name": "Kholi",
  "age": 19,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Asia"
},
{
  "name": "Natali",
  "age": 20,
  "sex": "Female",
  "region": "Europe"
},
{
  "name": "Mia",
  "age": 30,
  "sex": "Female",
  "region": "Europe"
},
{
  "name": "Sonu",
  "age": 20,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Asia"
},
{
  "name": "Mark",
  "age": 30,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Africa"
},
{
  "name": "Surith",
  "age": 25,
  "sex": "Female",
  "region": "Africa"
}]
```

first I need to create age range array using "ages" array

```js
[{
  "range": "0 - 19",
  "count": 0,
},
{
  "range": "20 - 39",
  "count": 0,
},
{
  "range": "40 - 59",
  "count": 0,
},
{
  "range": "60 - 100",
  "count": 0,
}
];
```

After that from "doctors" array need to get relevant doctors under that age range and need to increase the count like this.

```js
[{
  "range": "0 - 19",
  "count": 2,
},
{
  "range": "20 - 39",
  "count": 5,
},
{
  "range": "40 - 59",
  "count": 0,
},
{
  "range": "60 - 100",
  "count": 0,
}
];
```

Comment: Please show your attempt .

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  This site is to help you with *specific* problems that you're facing, not to write a complete solution from scratch.

Comment: I was trying with reduce method. but not able to do it.

Comment: _"I was trying with reduce method"_ - share that. That will be better than not showing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```js
const ages = [20,40,60];
let min = 0;
const ranges = ages.map((age) => {
  const max = age - 1; 
  range = {
    "range": min + " - " + max,
    "min": min,
    "max": max,
    "count": 0
  };
  min = age;
  return range;
});
ranges.push({"min":min, "max":99, "count":0, "range": min + " - 99"});

const doctors = [{
  "name": "Moruu",
  "age": 18,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Africa"
},
{
  "name": "Kholi",
  "age": 19,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Asia"
},
{
  "name": "Natali",
  "age": 20,
  "sex": "Female",
  "region": "Europe"
},
{
  "name": "Mia",
  "age": 30,
  "sex": "Female",
  "region": "Europe"
},
{
  "name": "Sonu",
  "age": 20,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Asia"
},
{
  "name": "Mark",
  "age": 30,
  "sex": "Male",
  "region": "Africa"
},
{
  "name": "Surith",
  "age": 25,
  "sex": "Female",
  "region": "Africa"
}];

ranges.forEach((range) => {
  const docs = doctors.filter((d) => d.age >= range.min && d.age <= range.max);
  range.count = docs.length;
});
console.log(ranges);
```

Comment: yeah. thank you. can you please share how do we create "ranges" array using "ages" array.